# Should I use primitive data types or wrapper data types in Builder Pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, builder

Is it better to use wrapper classes data type for the parameters in the builder pattern and then transform to primitive during build method to its primitive data type or is it better to use primitive data types throughout the builder pattern and do all data transformation of nullable data types in the controllers or the methods that calls the builder pattern?

```
   public Builder recent(final Boolean recent) {
        if (recent != null) {
            this.recent = recent;
        }
        return this;
    }
```

vs

```
    public Builder recent(final boolean recent) {
        this.recent = recent;
        return this;
    }
```

Comment: Completely opinion based, I think, but if you can use primitives please do that.  Wrapper classes carry extra overhead and it's somewhat poor practice to add overhead if you know you can do without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on whether a `null` value is valid.

Your two examples have slightly different semantics.

```
public Builder recent(final Boolean recent) {
        if (recent != null) {
            this.recent = recent;
        }
        return this;
    }
```

The above is essentially saying that `this.recent` could actually hold a `null` value (if its type is `Boolean` too), but once it gets set to a non-null value, it never goes back, even if the caller requires it and passes `null` (is it something you want)?

```
public Builder recent(final boolean recent) {
        this.recent = recent;
        return this;
    }
```

This is saying that `recent` can either be set to `true` or `false`. The caller will not be misguided into thinking he can set it back to `null` if `this.recent` is actually of type `Boolean`. If you have a sensible default, you would even opt to set `this.recent` to that default directly, minimising the chance of doing a mistake somewhere else getting a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: +1. It also depends if you **want** the caller to specify a boolean value explicitly, or if you are OK with a default boolean value. If you want the caller to specify a value, then a null Boolean can represent the absence of a value.